# iOS - How to Reset a UI Object to Default Style

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface, uitextfield

Is there a way to reset a UI object like `UITextField` to the default iOS look and feel?

I ask because I'm putting a red border around a textfield as a part of form validation, and I'm having trouble removing the border so that the UITextField looks *exactly* as before. I can get it really really close, but it's off just enough to be noticeable to someone who looks at iPhone screens all day :).

[image] [image]

This is my code to give the UITextField a red border.

```
textfield.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
textfield.layer.borderColor = [[[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor];
textfield.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default values are 0 for borderWidth and cornerRadius and black for borderColor.

```
textfield.layer.borderWidth = 0;
textfield.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
textfield.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
```

You can also save those values to some field just before changing them and use the saved values when you need to reset the field. This will even work if the default values change in future.

Comment: Thanks, @murat. Did you know this from experience or is it in the Apple documentation somewhere? p.s. I added a code sample to your answer :).

Comment: @Kyle I have used the second method to reset the look of a UITextField before, have just checked the stored values with the debugger to find out the default values.

Comment: not true for ios 9.  Which is probably why this is not the best answer.  Is there something that will survive os updates?